# Setting Color Tags in iCloud Drive for iOS

Tags: ios, icloud, finder-tag

I am currently using iCloud Drive with my Mac and iPad. On the Mac, I am able to add color labels to documents and folders to better organize my files.

I am wondering if it is possible to add these kinds of labels and colors to documents and folders in iCloud from my iPad?

Comment: This would be useful to see the tags from macOS finder when browsing the cloud.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I have found this is not possible using the iCloud Drive app for iOS.